# XML::Simple not well formed (invalid token) token at line

Tags: xml, perl, module

I am using the book [XML and Perl](http://www.amazon.co.uk/XML-Perl-Mark-Riehl/dp/0735712891) by Mark Riehl, and one of the first introductory programs is working with [`XML::Simple`](https://metacpan.org/module/XML::Simple), which I downloaded on to Fedora using CPAN.

I keep on getting this error

```
not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1
```

I tooled around with the XML document for a while, then loaded up another XML file and got the same exact error.

Is there something wrong with this module?

```
[FEDORA_CASPER@new-host-3 xmlandperl]$ cat page39convert_xml_to_html_simple
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict ;
use warnings ;

use XML::Simple ;
my $simple = XML::Simple ->new();
my $struct = $simple->XMLin("./symbolconfig.xml") ;
[FEDORA_CASPER@new-host-3 xmlandperl]$ ./page39convert_xml_to_html_simple
not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 5, byte 5 at /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/XML/Parser.pm line 187.
[FEDORA_CASPER@new-host-3 xmlandperl]$
```

Comment: What is on line 1, column 5 of your XML document? Sounds like you have some invalid XML. The error message is pretty clear.

Comment: I had to add a doc type to the top of the xml - it loads

Comment: Although *XML and Perl* is a pretty old book, much of it is still quite relevant. Not the stuff on XML::Simple though - XML::Simple should be avoided. Just skip those parts.

Comment: @capser: No, you *don't* need a `!DOCTYPE` in your XML, and if you don't show your data we can't tell what was really wrong. Remember that Stack Overflow posts are intended primarily as a resource for other users, and abandoning your question just because you think you no longer need a solution isn't very kind.

Answer (score 1):

By design - invalid XML should be fatal. Processing XML should abort on encountering an error.

Most modules for parsing XML will `die` when this occurs. You can trap this by using an `eval` block, but what you can't do is 'push through' parsing the XML, because the XML specification says no.

What you should really do is feed back to the person who gave you the XML, and hit them over the head with a rolled up copy of the documentation.

http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#dt-fatal

There is an XML validator to be had here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp

This page also re-iterates:

> The W3C XML specification states that a program should stop processing an XML document if it finds an error.

However, without a sample of your XML, I can only repeat what your error says: 
`not well-formed (invalid token) at line 1, column 5, byte 5`